# Fredholm integral equation of third kind

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, functional-equations

Let us consider the following integral equation
$$a(x)u(x) + \int\limits_0^2 {K(s,x)u(s)ds}  = f(x)$$
Let f in $L^p(0,1)$ for some $p \in [1,\infty]$ and let $K  \in L^q((0,2) \times (0,1))$. Assume that $a$ doesn't vanishe in any point of $(0,1)$. My question is: What are the optimal assumptions to ensure that this equation has a solution? 
In my opinion, if $K$ and $f$ are continuous with $K$ is lipschitz kernel then we can apply Picard's iterations to prove the existence, what about $L^p$?
Thank you.